# How i send some information to my foreground activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to send some `String` data to my previous opened activity which is running in foreground and without calling through `Intents`

Comment: naive way: save it somewhere(fx: SP) then load it in onResume ...

Comment: save it where i dont save in my external or internal storage

Comment: you don't wana save(SP stands for SharedPreferences), you don't wana use Intent ... then it is not possible ... (beside, it makes no sens - the prev activity may or may not still "alive")

Comment: "Is it possible to build an app without coding at all ?"

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is through `SharedPreferences`. SharedPreferences will write your data to a private file in a key/value within your app's apk that will persist even you turn your device off.

You can initialize `SharedPreferences` in onCreate like so:
`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE)`.

To store a value simply call: 
`sharedPreferences.edit().putString("myKey", stringValue).commit();`

To retrieve that value anywhere from your application, initialize SharedPreferences, and then use the following code: 
`String myData = sharedPreferences.getString("myKey");`

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface to do this "trick". I'll show you an example to send String.

Create an interface, like:

```
public interface Communicable {
    public void transportString(String data);
}
```

Then you implement this interface on your *Activity*:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Communicable {
    //any code

    @Override
    public void transportString(String data) {
        //do whatever what you wants
    }

    //any code
}
```

To finish, in constructor of your new class, use *Communicable* as parameter and pass your *Activity* to it:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Communicable communicable;

    public MyClass(Communicable communicable) {
        this.communicable = communicable;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
         //any code
         communicable.transportString("example");
    }
}
```

Another thing that you could do, is create a new class that extends *Application*, and use it to transport any data over your app.

Comment: What a terrible idea... Never, ever pass instance of Activity to the next Activity... Yes, you can use it for fragment to Activity communication... But not inter activity... Even via Application class... Just put any ui interactions into transportString and you are in deep sh*

Comment: Ohh, I never meant to use this between activities, I used before to communication between _Fragment_ and _Activity_. But thats good to add in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

easy way shared preference. Hard way Sqlite or txt file.